# Webpack 3 image src issue for React ( html-Loader & transform-react-jsx-img-import )

Tags: image, reactjs, webpack, loader, src

---

**U P D A T E D**
Fixed code in the repository

---

first of all i know there are like some posts about this topic, but they are so outdated (webpack 1 or 2)

**I'm trying to setup a webpack config for React images** avoiding the ugly `var myImage = require('./imagePath/image.jpg');`

It works only if i add an image via scss or css *(background image i.e.)*,but if i try to add image in the index.html or in a react component they are not generated.

I'm trying to use **file-loader**, **html-loader** and **transform-react-jsx-img-import**

I created **[this repository](https://github.com/HectorLS/webpack-for-react-projects)**, with the sample case.

You can clone it and just install dependencies via `npm install` or `yarn install`

I have been struggling with this the last 2 days, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
const autoprefixer      = require('autoprefixer'),
      DashboardPlugin   = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin'),
      ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
      HtmlPlugin        = require('html-webpack-plugin'),
      path              = require('path'),
      webpack           = require('webpack');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';



//////////////////////// FILEPATH ///////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const buildFolder = 'dist';
const PATHS = {
  src       : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  build     : path.resolve(__dirname, buildFolder),
  appJS     : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app.js'),
  indexHTML : path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.html')
}



//////////////////////// PLUGINS ////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const HtmlPluginOptions = {
  template: PATHS.indexHTML,
  minify: {
    collapseWhitespace: true
  },
  hash: true
};

const ExtractTextPluginOptions = {
  filename: '[name].bundle.css',
  disable: !isProd,
  allChunks: true,
  ignoreOrder: false
}

const devServerOptions = {
  contentBase: PATHS.build,
  compress: true,
  port: 6969,
  stats: 'errors-only',
  open: true,
  hot: true,
  openPage: ''
};

const pluginsDev = [
  new DashboardPlugin(),
  autoprefixer,
  new HtmlPlugin(HtmlPluginOptions),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(ExtractTextPluginOptions),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
];

const pluginsProd = [
  require('autoprefixer'),
  new HtmlPlugin(HtmlPluginOptions),
  new ExtractTextPlugin(ExtractTextPluginOptions)
];

var pluginsList = isProd ? pluginsProd : pluginsDev;



//////////////////////// LOADERS ////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const postcss = {
  loader: 'postcss-loader',
  options: {
    sourceMap: 'inline',
    plugins() {
      return [autoprefixer({ browsers: 'last 3 versions' })];
    }
  }
};

const stylesDev  = ['style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', postcss, 'sass-loader?sourceMap'];
const stylesProd = ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
  fallback: 'style-loader',
  use: ['css-loader', postcss, 'sass-loader'],
  publicPath: buildFolder
});

const styles = {
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: isProd ? stylesProd : stylesDev
};

const javascript = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  use: 'babel-loader',
  exclude: /node_modules/
}

const images = {
  test: /\.(jpe?g|svg|png|gif)$/i,
  use: [
    'file-loader?name=assets/img/[name].[ext]'
  ]
}

const html = {
  test: /\.(html)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      attrs: ['img:src', 'link:href']
    }
  }
}



//////////////////////// WEBPACK ////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    app: PATHS.appJS
  },
  output:  {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [javascript, styles, images, html]
  },
  devServer: devServerOptions,
  plugins: pluginsList
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

There are a *./src/index.html* file with an `<img>` tag
and also *./src/components/App.js* file with another `<img>` tag

Again, thanks in advance. Remember that you have the full example in **[this repository](https://github.com/HectorLS/webpack-for-react-projects)**, try got to show both logos (webpack and react logo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URLs starting with a `/` are not transformed by `html-loader` (see ['Root-relative' URLs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#root-relative-urls)). Most loaders follow this behaviour, because that allows you to use existing files that use files on the server, that were not processed with webpack. Additionally, if it interpreted the URL as a path (like in any JavaScript module), it would look in the root of your file system and that's not what you want here.

As you did it in you SCSS, you have to use a relative path.

```
<img src="./public/assets/img/logo--webpack.svg" alt="Logo Webpack"/>
```

In a React component you cannot use the `html-loader` because you're not actually writing HTML, but JSX, which is syntactic sugar that will be transformed into function calls. For details see [JSX In Depth](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).

That means you'll have to import the image and pass it to the `src` attribute.

```
import reactLogo from '../public/assets/img/logo--react.svg';

<img src={reactLogo} alt="Logo React"/>
```

You could probably use a Babel plugin to transform `<img>` tags and automatically add imports of the sources. From a quick search, I found [babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import](https://github.com/gvelo/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-img-import), although I don't know whether that works as it doesn't seem to be maintained.

Comment: Ok thank you so much ! i found a typo in my code with the initial /  slash, and now everything works without the ugly imports for the static images :D

Answer (score 0):

What I use at my webpack 3 config to load images is:

```
     {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|webp)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
```

and this code inside my react components:

```
import logo from '../../img/logo.png';

...

<img className={style.logo} src={logo} alt="logo" />
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, 
but thats exactly what i'm trying to avoid, with the html-loader you should be able to forget about imports/requires in the components and just use the path.

Comment: Ok, sorry for do not help you, the html-loader is one more compress layer after html-webpack-plugin?

Comment: Np thanks for try to help me, is a package to help with this src attribute problem, so i guess is executed before the html-webpack-plugin. https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-loader check it !